# How to merge two rows in a dataset in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I initially had another column called Minor Category that had more information about the crime category. However, I need less information to achieve my visualisation, so i dropped it.  This is why there are multiple Major Category rows with the same values (2 Burglary crimes in Barking and Dagenham)
I am trying to merge these similar rows together as one. so that numCrimes could have the total of each, and that each borough would have one kind of Major Category appear once.

Any idea how to achieve that?

```
df.drop('Minor Category', axis='columns', inplace=True)
df
```

```
Output: 

        Borough             Major Category                  numCrimes
Year            
2008    Barking and Dagenham    Burglary                      82.0
2008    Barking and Dagenham    Burglary                      59.0
2008    Barking and Dagenham    Criminal Damage               79.0
2008    Barking and Dagenham    Criminal Damage               142.0
2008    Barking and Dagenham    Criminal Damage               20.0
... ... ... ...
2018    Westminster             Violence Against the Person   386.0
2018    Westminster             Violence Against the Person   0.0
2018    Westminster             Violence Against the Person   41.0
2018    Westminster             Violence Against the Person   38.0
2018    Westminster             Violence Against the Person   109.0
```

Comment: something like `df.groupby(['Year', 'Borough', 'Major Category'])['numCrimes'].sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a pretty simple groupby operation:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Year','Borough','Major Category']).sum()

## if you need to get the columns back...
grouped.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(["Year", "Borough", "Major Category"]).sum()
```

or a variant thereof. Pretty sure your looking for a use of [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` and `agg` are the right functions to use here but we should be careful not to lose 'Year' that looks like an index in your df. So

```
(df.reset_index()
   .groupby(['Year','Borough','Major Category'], as_index = False)
   .agg(sum)
)
```

should do it; for your sample data it produces

```
    Year    Borough                 Major Category              numCrimes
0   2008    Barking and Dagenham    Burglary                    141.0
1   2008    Barking and Dagenham    Criminal Damage             241.0
2   2018    Westminster             Violence Against the Person 574.0
```